# Удалить уже несуществующую базу MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

На локальной машине (VS2017, SQL 2014) часто смотрю примеры проектов, которые идут в комплекте с базой данных. Проекты потом удаляю, а про базы забываю.

Хотел сейчас удалить их - но это не удаётся! Пишет, что не может найти файлы базы (ещё бы).

Пробовал следующие рецепты:

1. Удалить базу правым кликом через Delete из UI
2. Писал drop database - эффект тот же
3. Пытался сделать detach базы из SSMS из UI
4. Другие советы из темы [SSMS drop failed for database “Unable to open physical file”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29108340/5752652)
5. Советы из темы [How to delete (localdb) database if the file is gone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13411005/5752652)

У меня правда SSMS с ошибкой не валится, но и эффекта от этих решений нет.

Answer (score 1):

Помогло как ни странно [вот такое решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45848300/5752652):

```
SELECT 'EXEC sp_detach_db ''' + name + ''''
FROM sys.databases
;
```

Этот скрипт готовит строки для детача ВСЕХ баз данных (в т.ч. системных и тех, что реально есть), поэтому нужно аккуратно выбрать только те базы, которые нужны.

И это реально работает и базы пропадают в списке баз.